# Magnetoresistance from self current

Tags: electromagnetism, resistivity

I have done this question on physics forum but for some reason my question didn't receive any attention there(maybe because physics site is for theoretical physicists mostly) and I have this question.

When there is current in a wire, a magnetic field is created around the wire. Will it affect the resistance of the wire at all or do we need an external magnetic field? And cN

Comment: Do you really mean ["magnetoresistance,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoresistance) or are you thinking of ["inductance?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance)

Comment: JRE I am thinking of magnetoresistance an effect studied in spintronics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the magnetic field that is created by the current flowing in a wire is no better or worse than the external one (considering its geometry). You may get magnetoresistance as well as probably Hall effect.

The magnitude of these effects is another matter, of course.